# placing focus on input box in IE

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer

I have the following situation in a web application I am working on:

I have a form with a set of index field values that a user enters information into and then submits the form to the server.  Field validation takes place on the server.  If any field is found to be invalid, the form is redisplayed and I want to the input focus to automatically go to the first invalid field. I have the code in place to make it happen but the problem is that the focus is not being placed on the field in IE 10 (yet it is being placed in Firefox).

```
  placefocusonfirstinvalidindexfield();

  // After an attempt to upload has failed due to one or more invalid fields, then place the input focus automatically on the first
  // invalid field:
  function placefocusonfirstinvalidindexfield() {
    var hasattemptedupload = '@Model.HasAttemptedUpLoadNumeric';
    if (hasattemptedupload == 1) {
      var indexfirstinvalidfield = '@Model.GetIndexOfFirstInvalidField()';
      // focusIndexField(indexfirstinvalidfield);
      setTimeout(focusIndexField(indexfirstinvalidfield), 100);
    }
  }

  function focusIndexField(fieldindex) {
    var control = document.getElementById("field" + fieldindex);
    control.focus();
  }
```

In the code above, I have confirmed that the correct field is being referenced.  Everything appears to be as it should, except at the end of process, IE10 does not place the focus on the referenced field.  Why not and what would I have to do to make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Just attempted this in the console to test in IE. The following code worked fine when testing focus on the "Post your answer" text area on this page.

`setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("wmd-input").focus() }, 5000);`

Maybe there is something else in your code interfering with the focus? Have you tried extending the timeout value to see if it has something to do with that?

Comment: I tried extending it to 5 seconds and it still did not place the focus on the field in IE10.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to haxx around the DOM loading with this row right?

```
setTimeout(focusIndexField(indexfirstinvalidfield), 100);
```

That row doesn't work as you expect. The focusIndexField is executed instantly and the response of the function is delayed 100 ms by the setTimeout function.

This would work as you expect:

```
setTimeout(function() {focusIndexField(indexfirstinvalidfield)}, 100);
```

However, it's not a good solution. The code should be executed when the document is ready instead.

Comment: You are correct about the setTimeout function, but changing it as you said did not make the field get focus in IE 10.  Neither did executing the code when the document is ready, with or without the timeout.  IE10 is not respecting the focus() method.

Comment: Maybe you should try to reproduce the problem in a JS-fiddle so we get the html-code as well?